# include js and css file in specific views in rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-3

How Do I include / exclude specific css and js file in specific views in rails?

at the moment I include all basic files in the the application.html.erb but some files and css don't play nice together, and I'd like to explicitly include the files needed for every page/view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167805/using-rails-3-1-where-do-you-put-your-page-specific-javascript-code)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794961/rails-3-including-javascript-on-a-view